# Adding a round down feature on a program

Tags: python

My program is meant to allow the user to create a character that has two attributes with values. The attributes are called strength and skill. The attribute values are created by a random number between 1 and 12 being divided by a number between 1 and 4. The outcome is added to 10. The thing is decimals can occur, so i want my program to round down decimals. I want it to round down even if the number is for example 5.6. Then is would become 5. I have not a clue how to implement this to my current code. I would also like the information to be saved to a text file but this is less important. I'm a noob at python and i would appreciate the help, thanks.

My current code

```
from random import randint
Strenght = 10
Skill = 10

while True:
    character = str(input("Enter name of your character\n"))
    if character:
        print("Your characters name is",character)
        print("They have",Strenght + randint(1,12)/randint(1,4),"Strenght")
        print("And",Skill + randint(1,12)/randint(1,4),"Skill")


if input("Would you like to make another character? \n").lower() not in ("yes","y"):
    break
```

Comment: Not really relevant, but do you realize you throw away the results of your random rolls as sonn as you've gotten them ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use the math.floor() command. It always rounds down.

```
>>> import math
>>> print (math.floor(5.6))
5.0
```

You can also round up with `math.ceil()` or round to the nearest integer with `round()`.

Answer (score 2):

Since both of the numbers you're dividing are integers, you can use the integer divide `//` to produce an integer output with the remainder dropped.

```
>>> print 17 // 3
5
>>> from __future__ import division
>>> print 17 / 3
5.66666666667
```